# How to animate images running across the whole screen in swift

Tags: swift, animation, uiview

So I am new to swift and I am trying to make a car game where there is a player car and opponent cars. The opponent cars will run through the screen and repeat until the game is over. I am implementing the opponent cars now but I am having a problem where the animation of the opponent cars only runs through half of the screen, until they disappear and start the loop again. How would I change this so that the opponent cars run through the entire screen? Here is my current code for the opponent cars:

```
  //animation of opponent car1

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 4, delay: 0.0, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat], animations:
            {

                self.car1image.center.y += self.view.bounds.width



                }, completion: nil
        )


//opponent car2

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 4, delay: 1.0, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat], animations:
            {

                self.car2image.center.y += self.view.bounds.width


        }, completion: nil
        )

//opponent car3

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 4, delay: 2.0, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat], animations:
            {

                self.car3image.center.y += self.view.bounds.width


        }, completion: nil
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the view **width** to the y position. You should be adding the view **height**. (And actually you should probably add the *screen* height, not the view height.)

And it would really be better to do math that calculated the distance between the car image view and the bottom of the screen and add that amount rather than adding the view/screen height, since adding the full screen height will make the image view go past the bottom of the screen unless it starts out centered at the top of the screen.

Comment: If I've answered your question then you should accept my answer.